# CSS Fixed top menu not working on mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I have a site that is a one page scroll type.  I have a fixed menu at the top and this works fine on desktop browsers.  It does not work on mobile however, and the menu just stays at the top and when you scroll down it disappears.

My CSS for the header is:

```
#header {
background: url('../_images/menu_bg.png');
padding-top: 10px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9000;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: http://www.larcohintonburg.com/css/styleMobile.css - `line 1092` you have `#header { position: relative; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

line: 1092 of your styleMobile.css you have this css snippet:

```
#header {
 positioN: relative;
}
```

Removing that fixes the issue.